# Read local file in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a question wanna ask you.
I have the json file have contain the relative path of all files located in the folder contain this json file.

example:

```
In my folder: D:\Data\Files\file1.txt
              D:\Data\Files\file2.jpg
              D:\Data\info.json
In json file: Files:{
                 path: Files\file1.txt,
                 path: Files\file2.jpg,
                    }
```

Can I read all files by relative path file in the json file in javascript?

If it possible please help me some example code.

Sorry for my bad english.

Many thanks.

Comment: are you using nodejs? or what javascript? It's impossible in browser.

Comment: need an extra info on this

Comment: @AntonLee — Since the question is tagged [tag:angular], "in browser" is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: it is not possible using relative path. you need to use the file reader api. but you need to improve your question to get an answer

Comment: i use angular 4 sir, i wanna read file in browser, so it is impossible right?